# Can I create PushTopic on CaseComment

Tags: community, pushtopic, case-comment

I am trying to create a pushtopic to listen to the CaseComment object. Typed the following in the ApexExec:

```
PushTopic pushTopic = new PushTopic();
pushTopic.Name = 'CaseCommentTopic';
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT Id FROM CaseComment';
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 36.0;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationCreate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUpdate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUndelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationDelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForFields = 'Referenced';
insert pushTopic;*
```

I get the below error:

> "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD, 'CaseComment' is not supported: [Query]"*

Can someone please help me understand why this error occurs

Answer (score 1):

This is just because its not supported, you can find reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/supported_soql.htm)

> The following are examples of supported SOQL statements.
>
> - Custom object
>
>   ```
>   SELECT Id, MyCustomField__c FROM MyCustomObject__c
>   ```
> - Standard objects (may include custom fields)
>
>   - Account
>
>     ```
>     SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE NumberOfEmployees > 1000
>     ```
>   - Campaign
>
>     ```
>     SELECT Id, Name FROM Campaign WHERE Status = 'Planned'
>     ```
>   - Case
>
>     ```
>     SELECT Id, Subject FROM Case WHERE Status = 'Working' AND IsEscalated = TRUE
>     ```
>   - Contact
>
>     ```
>     SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact;
>     ```
>   - Lead
>
>     ```
>     SELECT Id, Company FROM Lead WHERE Industry = 'Computer Services'
>     ```
>   - Opportunity
>
>     ```
>     SELECT Id, Name, Amount FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate < 2011-06-14
>     ```
>   - Task
>
>     ```
>     SELECT Id, Subject, IsClosed, Status FROM Task WHERE isClosed = TRUE
>     ```